# Datetime format Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am having problem understanding datetime format in rails. I have stored a date which is called 'starts_at' and type is datetime using postman.

```
{
    "reservation": {
        "starts_at": "2020-1-7 7:00 pm",
        "expires_at": "2020-1-7 9:00 pm"
    }
}
```

I want to enter another date and want to validate the date I enter every time be in an interval of 120 minutes after.
So I tried plucking out 'starts_at' from my model 'reservations' and tried to loop through each 'starts_at' date and comparing their difference with my new entered dates' 'starts_at'.

```
# I have defined scope to pluck the 'starts_at' in reservation.rb
# scope :starts_at, -> { pluck(:starts_at) }

def create
   Reservation.starts_at.each do |starts_at|
        time_diffs = time_diff_in_minutes(date_time_conversion(starts_at) - params[:starts_at].to_datetime)
        if time_diffs < 120
          return
        end
        @reservation = Reservation.new(processed_params)
        reservation.save
      end
   end


  private

  def date_time_conversion(starts_at)
    starts_at.to_datetime
  end

  def time_diff_in_minutes(time_calc)
    (time_calc * 24 * 60).to_s.to_i.abs
  end
```

I have one value in database which has starts_at datetime = "2020-1-7 7:00 pm".
When I run debugger and checked the plucked value it has a format something like

```
Tue, 07 Jan 2020 18:00:00 +06 +06:00
```

And the format of the date I entered was something like

```
 Tue, 07 Jan 2020 19:00:00 +0000
```

I want to understand what does +06 +6:00 means and how does postgresql database store datetime object and return format. Your help shall be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: +06 +6:00 Is the difference between your local timezone and UTC. Checkout https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm for more explanation.